# iOS Safari top and bottom bar issue

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, mobile-safari

I have a an application that has three fixed sections:

1) Header - Top

2) Main content - Center

3) Footer - Bottom

The main content scrolls using `overflow: auto` and has the scroll bar contained within its own dimensions rather than the entire body (which is what i want). However because of my app structure, scrolling the main content area, safari on iOS doesn't hide the `top address bar` and `bottom action bar`.

I have tried several suggestion found in blog posts and stackoverflow but none has worked.

Anyone who has faced similar issue and resolved it please kindly shine some light :)

**Here are some solutions that i have tried:**

1) Adding 44px `padding-bottom` on `<body>`

2) Adding 44px `padding-bottom` on `<html>`

3) Using `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`

4) JS snippet to `window.scrollTo(0, 1)` wrapped in `setTimeout`

*None of the above has worked for me.*

Answer (score 2):

A workaround would be to set the html height to 100% and scroll in containers in your site. The downside of that is, that you have the native bars visible all the time. The financial times does it like that on all devices https://app.ft.com/ but again you waste a lot of space on an iphone 5 for instance.

We had another solution which kinda solved it for us. Since the native bar only appears when you scroll up. Our navigation did the same. So if you scroll down our menu disappears and if you scroll up it appears. Doesn't feel so weird and you don't waste all the space all the time.

Answer (score 0):

My only "work-around" was to use `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">` and have my users add my site to their home screen.

Invoking the site this way causes the address and action bars to stay fully hidden.